# Flask ImportError

Tags: python, flask

Taking my first steps with Flask and python in general. I'm trying to build a very basic app using Flask-Admin to build a Model View page.

All the code samples from the Flask and Flask-Admin run as they should and the ModelView can run basic CRUD on my database.

But, when I use a separate `models.py` file (from [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/)), things go wrong.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///database/db.db"
app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'flatly'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import *

class PostView(ModelView):
    edit_modal = True

admin = Admin(app, name='ProjectX', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(PostView(Post, db.session))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**models.py**

```
from app import db

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
    return '<Post {}>'.format(self.title)
```

When I run `python app.py` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from models import *
  File "/Users/me/Sites/projectx/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "/Users/me/Sites/projectx/app.py", line 18, in <module>
    admin.add_view(PostView(Post, db.session))
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined
```

When I change `from models import *` to `from models import Post` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from models import Post
  File "/Users/me/Sites/projectx/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "/Users/me/Sites/projectx/app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from models import Post
ImportError: cannot import name 'Post'
```

It seems to me that `db` is not available in `models.py`? Is this a problem with circular imports and if so, how can I fix this?

EDIT *I may have messed some things up wrt my virtual environments (I think I have both pipenv and autoenv running) and there's some confusion with pip / python2 / python3. But I doubt this has anything to do with the problem. This app definitely runs on 3.6.5*

Comment: try to `import models` then use `from models import Post`

Comment: No luck. Adding `import models` just above the `from models import Post` line changes nothing.

Comment: just a trick though go to `/Users/me/Sites/projectx/` open terminal/command prompt,type python then there do `from models import Post` if it happens then issue is related to your execution path

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I try that I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'`referring to line 2 of `app.py`. Execution path problem it is then? How could I fix this?

Comment: in your ide setting you have to set the execution path to the folder where app,py is ,

Comment: Not using an IDE, just Sublime Text and iTerm. Could you point me to some resources on where / how to set the execution path? I guess this should be done on a per-app basis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186242/discussion-between-stef-and-prashant-rana).

Answer (score 2):

You're worked your way in to something called "the circular import problem." In this case, it happens like this.

Python begins parsing/evaluating `app.py`. Midway in, it finds `from models import *` (or one of the other variants you tried).

The parsing/evaluating of `app.py` is temporarily suspended to pull in symbols from `models`.

Python begins parsing/evaluating `models.py`, and immediately encounters `from app import db`.

For very slightly convoluted (but sensible) reasons, Python then wants to complete the parsing/evaluating of `app.py`, but when it does, it encounters the reference to `Post`, which hasn't yet been defined because the parsing/evaluating of `models.py` was suspended. Python then raises a `NameError`.

The easiest way I know to resolve this it to create a separate `views.py`, which would look something like

```
from app import admin, db
from models import Post
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class PostView(ModelView):
    edit_modal = True
admin.add_view(PostView(Post, db.session)
```

then import it at the end of `app.py` after you've imported `models`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand the the circular import problem but no matter what I try (your solution and many possible variations) I keep hitting the same problem.