# Python, unable to import

Tags: python

I've asked a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056892/flask-importerror/54059124) and without having found a solution I've simplified my code as much as possible to illustrate the problem.

The code below runs fine, until I include `from run import db` in `models.py`. Then I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Site'` (full error below)

However when I use `from models import *` then everything runs fine again (but I don't want to do that).

Why does this happen?

**run.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///database/db.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy()

from models import Site
# from models import *
print (Site.hello())
```

**models.py**

```
# Uncommenting the import line below produces the error
# from run import db

class Site():

    def hello():
        print ("hello world")
```

**Error**

```
    (venv) abc:projectx me$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 16, in <module>
    from models import Site
  File "/Users/me/projectx/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from run import db
  File "/Users/me/projectx/run.py", line 16, in <module>
    from models import Site
ImportError: cannot import name 'Site'
```

Directory structure

```
projectx
    __pycache__
    database
    venv
    __init__.py
    run.py
    models.py
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `from .models import Site` ?

Comment: Are the 2 files in the same directory?

Comment: Can you add the tree of your architecture please? Be aware you can remove everything that deals with Flask, we do not need it

Comment: @noamgot yes they are.

Comment: @seralouk yes I have, this gives me: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: are run.py and models.py at the same level? how do you execute run.py?

Comment: `run` imports `model` and `model` imports `run`; you have a circular dependency. While the first import of `model` is trying to define the module, `run` tries to import  `Site` from `model`, but that hasn't been defined yet by the first import. I suggest looking at your design again to avoid the circular reference.

Comment: @naivepredictor I run via terminal: `python run.py` and yes both files are at the same level, in the root of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing `Site` from module "models" into module "run" and `db` from module "run" into module "models" so you have a circular dependency problem.

You should keep your models simple so I would remove the dependency from module "run" inside "models" but if you still need it, then you should consider creating a single module that includes both because in this case, it would be sensible to make a single unit containing all dependant code.

Comment: Indeed, I created a separate db module and included that in both files, and now it runs fine. So simple yet so hard to spot. Thank you.